# Magento admin panel gives 404 when trying to enter cms pages

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento 1.4.1.1 which works great other then the 404 when I'm trying to enter CMS/Pages in the navigation.
All other pages work great and even other items in CMS menu, only Pages gives 404.
What should I do?

Comment: Do you have any extensions enabled, and have you modified the core system in any way?

Comment: Check if CMS url include `index.php`, if not try to add it.

Answer (score 38):

Had this exact problem..

You are getting a 404 on CMS pages because of the remains of old store views still hanging around in the database after deleting store views from Magento admin, to clean up ( delete ) old unused CMS pages for store views you have deleted run this MySQL query.

```
DELETE FROM cms_page_store WHERE store_id NOT IN (SELECT store_id FROM core_store)
```

You could also use an app like phpmyadmin to manually look for CMS entries that have store IDs that you know not to be in use, but this could get messy.

Original source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/18223/

Comment: Thank you a lot, you saved me so much time

Comment: Awesome, had exactly this problem after removing a store view :) Thanks!

Comment: Great answer. You saved my time.