# 404 page not found when trying to access CMS -> Pages in admin panel Magento 1.8.1.0

Tags: magento, content-management-system, http-status-code-404

Shortly after configuring my site to have two separate websites I could not access CMS -> Pages to manage my pages.

I followed the steps on this two links http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/18223/ | [Magento admin panel gives 404 when trying to enter cms pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866013/magento-admin-panel-gives-404-when-trying-to-enter-cms-pages) where they mention “cms_page_store” table. But that table obviously does not exist in 1.8.1.0 Magento version.

Comment: Daniel,It has not cms_page_stores table,thus create issue

Comment: Can you instruct me what could I do to pass the 404 error message?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866013/magento-admin-panel-gives-404-when-trying-to-enter-cms-pages

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I had to engage Magento freelancer who solved my problem which was caused by duplicate database tables -  only solution info provided from a freelancer.

Comment: I'd love to know which tables he was talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but still happened to me in Magento 1.9.1.0. Some leftover CMS-Page database entries were referencing a store_id of a store that no longer existed after I deleted it.

**So here's what solved it for me:**

- Find out the ids of your stores: Under `System > Manage Stores` in the column `Store View Name` look for the Store's id that pop up when hovering the link and also in the link url (e.g. `...admin/system_store/editStore/store_id/3/key/...`)
- To be safe, make a database backup under `System > Tools > Backups`
- Go to your database and find the table `cms_page_store`. Delete all entries with a store id in the field `store_id` that points to a store, that does no longer exist.
- Refresh `CMS > Pages`, 404 should be gone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866013/magento-admin-panel-gives-404-when-trying-to-enter-cms-pages helped me