# magento 404 on cms page in adminhtml in module cms->page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have trouble when I click on `Admin -> CMS -> Page` and I get `404`error. Maybe any body had this error early? How to debug router in magento? and i think this is community or local extensions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866013/magento-admin-panel-gives-404-when-trying-to-enter-cms-pages maybe helpful

Comment: var/log/system.log  check log file.

Comment: @safinchacko system.log, exception.log and apache log is clear. I set my question after check logs and not found error...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity Why? this question about routing bug why this produce I don't know I not have logs, and script run with out errors... I can paste core block code but why?

Comment: @Naumov - But it's not a bug in code you've written, so it's off-topic. We can help you when you get stuck writing your own code, but we're not a debugging service for every piece of software ever created.

Answer (score 0):

I explain the error she code
in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Page/Grid.php

```
$collection->setFirstStoreFlag(true);
```

when, application get first store for get all pages on the first.
after if first storage in table `cms_page_store` not exist in table `core_store` then I get error and 404 error not found. 
How to fix I run two queries on my mysql server first delete all not exist store in table `core_page_store` by this query

```
delete from `cms_page_store` where `store_id` not in(
  select `core_store`.`store_id` as `id` from `core_store`
);
```

and delete all page in not exist store from cms_page by this query:

```
delete from `cms_page` where `page_id` not in(
     select `cms_page_store`.`page_id` as `id` from `cms_page_store`
);
```

and finish it's work, please if you read the answer you need create dump table `cms_page_store` and `cms_page` for repair the table if you make error.